# How do i get a limited number of rows for each value in a field? (db is mysql but could be changed if easier)

Tags: mysql, database

I found this difficult to search for this question. I have a table of sports fixtures (`tbl_fixture`) and a table of sports participants (`tbl_participant`) which have a many-to-many relationship via a linking table (`tbl_fixture_participant`)

I need to return the most recent 3 fixtures (ie latest `tbl_fixture.start_datetime`) of multiple participants and whether they won each of the fixtures, (eg more recent 3 fixtures of participant 1 and most recent 3 fixtures of participant 2, and most recent 3 fixtures of participant 3, with each record returning the `fixture_id`, `participant_id`, `start_datetime` and `is_winner` fields).

The number of participants that i need to get the data for could be between 1 and 100.

If there's a better way to structure my data, or a better database for this type of query (graph db?) then i'm happy to look into those.

Here's a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_fixture (
  fixture_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  start_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_participant (
  participant_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_fixture_participant (
  fixture_id INT NOT NULL,
  participant_id INT NOT NULL,
  is_winner TINYINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fixture_id)
    REFERENCES tbl_fixture (fixture_id)
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (participant_id)
    REFERENCES tbl_participant (participant_id)
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO tbl_fixture (fixture_id, start_datetime)
VALUES (1, "2021-01-14 15:00:00"),
(2, "2021-01-13 16:00:00"),
(3, "2021-01-12 17:00:00"),
(4, "2021-01-11 15:00:00"),
(5, "2021-01-19 16:00:00"),
(6, "2021-01-18 17:00:00"),
(7, "2021-01-05 15:00:00"),
(8, "2021-01-03 16:00:00"),
(9, "2021-01-03 17:00:00"),
(10, "2021-01-11 15:00:00"),
(11, "2021-01-12 16:00:00"),
(12, "2021-01-13 17:00:00"),
(13, "2021-01-14 15:00:00"),
(14, "2021-01-19 16:00:00");


INSERT INTO tbl_participant (participant_id, name) VALUES 
( 1,"Team 1"),
( 2,"Team 2"),
( 3,"Team 3");

INSERT INTO tbl_fixture_participant (fixture_id, participant_id, is_winner)
VALUES (1, 1, 0)
  ,(2, 1, 1)
  ,(2, 2, 0)
  ,(3, 1, 1)
  ,(12, 2, 0)
  ,(4, 3, 1)
  ,(4, 2, 0)
  ,(6, 3, 1)
  ,(1, 2, 1)
  ,(10, 1, 1)
  ,(5, 2, 0)
  ,(6, 1, 0)
  ,(11, 1, 1)
  ,(14, 1, 0)
  ,(7, 2, 0)
  ,(7, 3, 1)
  ,(3, 3, 0)
  ,(8, 1, 0)
  ,(5, 3, 1)
  ,(13, 2, 0)
  ,(8, 3, 1)
  ,(13, 3, 1)
  ,(9, 1, 0)
  ,(9, 2, 1)
  ,(10, 2, 0)
  ,(11, 3, 0)
  ,(12, 3, 1)
  ,(14, 3, 1);
```

And [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bc784/5) of same.

I would like the data to come back like:

| fixture_id | start_datetime | participant_id | is_winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 2021-01-19T16:00:00Z | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 2021-01-18T17:00:00Z | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-14T15:00:00Z | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-01-19T16:00:00Z | 2 | 0 |
| 13 | 2021-01-14T15:00:00Z | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-14T15:00:00Z | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Ah thanks! I've created a SQL Fiddle. I'll update the question

Comment: "the last 6 fixtures of multiple participants" - what does "last" mean?

Comment: @Strawberry
Thanks for the advice and for updating the question! i’ve simplified it to “most recent 3” rather than “last 6" to make it easier to read.
I’ve also added a table of what i'd like the output to look like

Comment: Also, the fiddle implies that you're using version 5.6. Is that correct?

Comment: And, in the sample data, dates increase in accordance with ids. Will that always be true?

Comment: @Strawberry Apologies for the missing information! I am currently on mysql v5.6 but i'm happy to try solutions which would involve migrating to a different mysql version or even a different database. Also, i've updated the question to reflect the fact that the start_datetime will not always increase along with the fixture_id.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED TO REFLECT FACT THAT DATES ARE NOT NECESSARILY SEQUENTIAL...

E.g. (for older versions of MySQL)...

```
SELECT x.*
     , fx.start_datetime
  FROM fixture_participant x
  JOIN fixture fx
    ON fx.fixture_id = x.fixture_id
  
  JOIN fixture_participant y
    ON y.participant_id = x.participant_id
  JOIN fixture fy
    ON fy.fixture_id = y.fixture_id
   AND fy.start_datetime > fx.start_datetime

 GROUP 
    BY x.fixture_id
     , x.participant_id
     , x.is_winner
     , fx.start_datetime
HAVING COUNT(x.fixture_id) <=3
 ORDER
    BY participant_id,fixture_id;
```

...or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to play around with it and see if i can understand what it's doing.
It does look like it should be `AND fy.start_datetime >= fx.start_datetime` rather than `AND fy.start_datetime > fx.start_datetime` though - based on my expected results and the actual results it returns